# Multiple requests shut down MySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, database

I have some problems with my MySQL database.

I configured a server with the database and other services (apache, php) and put run multiple applications. There are two problems:

1. Every day at the same time MySQL fails, and I must go and restart it.
2. Every time I reload the website many times continuously MySQL fails, and again I need to restart it.

MySQL logs show:

```
140107  0:09:29 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
140107  0:09:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140107  0:09:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140107  0:09:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140107  0:09:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140107  0:09:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
InnoDB: mmap(68681728 bytes) failed; errno 12
140107  0:09:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140107  0:09:29 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140107  0:09:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140107  0:09:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140107  0:09:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140107  0:09:29 [ERROR] Aborting
140107  0:09:29 [Note] /usr/sbin/myqld: Shutdown complete
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You don't have enough memory available.  See [this related question](http://serverfault.com/questions/451307/innodb-mysql-plugin-disabled) from server fault.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of mysql database. The server was running out of memory to solve, I used SWAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
InnoDB: mmap(68681728 bytes) failed; errno 12

---

$ perror 12
OS error code  12:  Cannot allocate memory
```

You've run out of memory. If possible, add more RAM to the server. Otherwise, you should adjust your database settings to reduce memory usage. Swapping will only lead to poor performance. To see how much memory is in use, run the `free` command at the console.

More information is available in this Stack Overflow thread: [MySQL maximum memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage)